# How to hide scrollbar in UIStackView?

Tags: ios, xcode, scrollbar, uistackview

I am using Xcode 10.1 and am programming using Swift in the `ViewController.swift` file.

I have a horizontally scrolling UIStackView that works perfectly. The only issue is that the scrollbar appears whenever I begin to scroll. I looked online and there were plenty of tutorials on how to make similar UIStackViews but none of them explained how to hide the scrollbar. Does anybody know how to do this?

```
stackView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

Gives me the error

> "Value of type 'UIStackView' has no member
>   'showsHorizontalScrollIndicator' "

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you need to call `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` On you scrollview. Second there are two ways of doing this : -

**1 Programatically**

```
// To hide vertical Indicator
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
// To hide horizontal Indicator
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

**2 By Storyboard**

Select you scrollview and uncheck the following buttons

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`showsHorizontalScrollindicator` is property of UIScrollView, but not the `UIStackView`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619380-showshorizontalscrollindicator

To hide scrollIndicator set this to `false` for your scrollView